# Need help with the following putnam problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, contest-math

Problem:

Let $f : R^2 → R$ be a function such that $f(x, y) + f(y, z) +
f(z, x) = 0$ for all real numbers $x$, $y$, and $z$. Prove that there exists a function $g : R → R$ such that $f(x, y) = g(x) − g(y)$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Approach:

$f(x,y) = -f(y,z) -f(z,x)$

Somehow the z terms on the right side have to cancel out to create an expression in terms of just x and y.

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=f(x,0)$ fulfills the condition, plugging $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ into the equation so we get
$$f(0,0)=0$$ when we take $$(x,y,z)=(x,0,0)$$ so we have $f(x,0)+f(0,x)=0$ and when we set
$(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$ we have
$$f(x,y)=-f(y,0)-f(0,x)=g(x)-g(y)$$

Comment: whoaaa. Can you explain the trace of your thinking?

Comment: wait but why do you need the first steps?. Is it enough to say $(x,y,z) = (x,y,0)$?